# Creating a smooth Animation in Android Development

Tags: android, animation

can anyone help me out.
I am tring to create a cool animation in Android using the code bellow. 
The Image moves but the movement is not smooth I want something that will look like a real car movement.

```
    ImageView car=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.car);
    TranslateAnimation animation= new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 500.0f,
            0.0f, -500.0f);
    animation.setDuration(1000);  // animation duration50
    animation.setRepeatMode(1);   // repeat animation (left to right, right to left )
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.scaleCurrentDuration(500);

    car.startAnimation(animation);  // start animation
```

Comment: Maybe try [`setInterpolator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setInterpolator(android.view.animation.Interpolator)), accelerateDecceleratInterpolator is probably what you want

Comment: Please can you show an example of how to use it

Comment: Just something like `animation.setInterpolator(new AcceleratDecelerateInterpolator());`, don't have any example at hand right now

Comment: I tired using it with my animation like bellow but with no effect.
  animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve it.

Here you can pass the marker, the updated lat long that you might receive in the location change listener and the bearing.

```
    void changePositionSmoothly(final Marker myMarker, final LatLng newLatLng, final Float bearing) {

        final LatLng startPosition = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
        final LatLng finalPosition = newLatLng;
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final Interpolator interpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
        final float durationInMs = 3000;
        final boolean hideMarker = false;

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            long elapsed;
            float t;
            float v;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                myMarker.setRotation(bearing);
                // Calculate progress using interpolator
                elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                t = elapsed / durationInMs;
                v = interpolator.getInterpolation(t);

                LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(
                        startPosition.latitude * (1 - t) + finalPosition.latitude * t,
                        startPosition.longitude * (1 - t) + finalPosition.longitude * t);

                myMarker.setPosition(currentPosition);

                // Repeat till progress is complete.
                if (t < 1) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    if (hideMarker) {
                        myMarker.setVisible(false);
                    } else {
                        myMarker.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```